# What does "⌨" mean as an Intellij keyboard shortcut?

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

In the Mac docs for IntelliJ Idea they use the keyboard icon (⌨) for some of the keyboard shortcuts. It implies one should hit all the keys, but on usb inputs you can only press six keys simultaneously (and this is the case on current Apple laptops).

Joking aside, how do you translate the following into plain English instructions?

> ⌥⌘⌨ *, 1

See an example in the docs [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/code-folding.html#folding_menu). Make sure to have your keymap set to `Mac OS X (10.5+)` (do this in the upper right hand corner)

Comment: Wow, that looks confusing. Have you tried pressing plausible keyboard combinations and seeing what activates the shortcut?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Apparently, it indicates that the symbol is on the **NumPad** section of the keyboard:

[image: numpad]

<kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>NumPad *</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd>

Press the first 3 keys together, release them, then press <kbd>1</kbd>.

`⌨` (keyboard) emoji is a weird choice for `NumPad` and [there is an open request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-170482) to change it back to `NumPad`, feel free to vote.

Comment: Macbook doesn't have the numpad key? Does it mean for mac os we simply need to remap them?

Comment: @MongH.Ng yes, just change the bindings

Comment: What is there **Expand all to level** but no **Collapse all to level**? How do I collapse a **certain** level?

Comment: @MongH.Ng Let me suggest you use the same mappings as VS Code for consistency: chorded `⌘K ⌘1` … `⌘K ⌘5`

Comment: @AlaaM. Two-step process: first, trigger the shortcut to `Collapse` then do the `Expand to level`. I think this would work for both `Expand` and `Expand All`

Comment: This is a KILLLLLLLLLLLER feature. I have a feeling it's gonna change my life as the code files in my company are easily thousands of lines long!